# Does Visual Studio have a setting for saving the swap panes when viewing xaml?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml, defaults

I am constantly swapping panes when viewing xaml (xaml on top, design on bottom or not showing at all). Is there a place in Visual Studio where I can set a default for how I want to view xaml files?

My google powers haven't revealed anything...

Comment: It remembers for individual files, but I don't know about a global preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a default setting for XAML on top/bottom. However, there is a default setting to always open a document in full XAML view:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML >
>   Miscellaneous: Always open document is
>   full XAML view

Comment: In VS 2015 see the `Tools > Options > XAML Designer` node